# Cannot start graphite carbon carbon-cache service fails with error code 1 on Ubuntu Release16.04

Tags: graphite

I am trying to install graphite carbon using

> sudo apt-get install graphite-carbon

it installs, but when running carbon-cache service it throws this.

> Job for carbon-cache.service failed because the control process exited
>   with error code. See "systemctl status carbon-cache.service" and
>   "journalctl -xe" for details.

Then this

> systemctl status carbon-cache.service

```
● carbon-cache.service - Graphite Carbon Cache
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/carbon-cache.service; enabled; 
vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-11-23 12:46:52 IST; 2ms ago
  Process: 16315 ExecStart=/usr/bin/carbon-cache --config=/etc/carbon/carbon.conf --pidfile=/var/run/carbon-cache.pid --logdir=/var/log/carbon/ start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 23 12:46:52 aditya-B250M-D3H carbon-cache[16315]:     self.subOptions.parseOptions(rest)
Nov 23 12:46:52 aditya-B250M-D3H carbon-cache[16315]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/usage.py", line 277, in parseOptions
Nov 23 12:46:52 aditya-B250M-D3H carbon-cache[16315]:     self.postOptions()
Nov 23 12:46:52 aditya-B250M-D3H carbon-cache[16315]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/carbon/conf.py", line 230, in postOptions
Nov 23 12:46:52 aditya-B250M-D3H carbon-cache[16315]:     if whisper.CAN_FALLOCATE:
Nov 23 12:46:52 aditya-B250M-D3H carbon-cache[16315]: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CAN_FALLOCATE'
Nov 23 12:46:52 aditya-B250M-D3H systemd[1]: carbon-cache.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 23 12:46:52 aditya-B250M-D3H systemd[1]: Failed to start Graphite Carbon Cache.
Nov 23 12:46:52 aditya-B250M-D3H systemd[1]: carbon-cache.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 23 12:46:52 aditya-B250M-D3H systemd[1]: carbon-cache.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package graphite-carbon (--configure):
```

[image]

Comment: What should i do to resolve this and install graphite completely.

Comment: Done adding text, please help on this